Weird behavior of a spline -Unity 3D
Hello I am using https://github.com/CMDRSpirit/RollercoasterDesigner this package to make my one roller coaster. Sadly it is not very polished but I have one problem with it. When I set the StartSlope Variable it sets its own. (See Attached video)
I tried to get Chat GPT do help me fix it but that didn't work. I came to the conclusion that this line might be the source of the problem float3 startSlope = lengthsq(StartSlope) != 0 ? StartSlope : float.NaN; Here is the script and the github project
